# How to conclude ratio from a function by using SymPy buil-in module?

Tags: sympy

If ((2x-y)/(x+3y))=2/3, what is the radio of x to y?

Which built-in module or function I can use to solve this problem in one step?

I have tried "solve()", it didn't work

solve((2x-y)/(x+3y))-(2/3), [x, y])

The result was [9y/4], which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and replace `x` with a variable representing the ratio, say `r`, in terms of y:

```
>>> from sympy import S
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> eq=((2*x-y)/(x+3*y))-S(2)/3
>>> solve(eq.subs(x, r*y), r)  # if r = x/y then x = r*y
[9/4]
```

You could use SymPy to determine that replacement by solving the ratio relationship, Equality, for you in terms of `x`:

```
>>> solve(eq.subs(x, solve(Eq(r, x/y), x)[0]), r)
[9/4]
```

or `y`

```
>>> solve(eq.subs(y, solve(Eq(r, x/y), y)[0]), r)
[9/4]
```

Comment: Smart solution! Thank you so much